# Unknown column in field list when use raw in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a working mysql query like this:

```
SELECT mc.cart_id, mc.mystore_user_id, MIN(ci.created_at) AS created_at
FROM dmspro_mys_cart AS mc
INNER JOIN dmspro_mys_cart_item AS ci
ON ci.cart_id = mc.cart_id
WHERE mc.is_noticed = 0 AND ci.created_at < '2019-10-08 07:08:39'
GROUP BY mc.cart_id
```

And I converted it to query builder in my Laravel project:

```
public function getMinCreatedAt($cartTime)
    {
        $oSelect = $this->select("{$this->table}.cart_id", "{$this->table}.mystore_user_id",\DB::raw('MIN(ci.created_at) AS created_at'))
                        ->join('cart_item AS ci', 'ci.cart_id', '=', "{$this->table}.cart_id")
                        ->where("{$this->table}.is_noticed", '=', 0)
                        ->where('ci.created_at', '<', $cartTime)
                        ->groupBy("{$this->table}.cart_id")
                        ->get();

        return $oSelect;
    }
```

But when I run this, I got error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ci.created_at' in 'field list'
>   (SQL: select `dmspro_mys_cart`.`cart_id`,
>   `dmspro_mys_cart`.`mystore_user_id`, MIN(ci.created_at) AS created_at
>   from `dmspro_mys_cart` inner join `dmspro_mys_cart_item` as
>   `dmspro_mys_ci` on `dmspro_mys_ci`.`cart_id` =
>   `dmspro_mys_cart`.`cart_id` where `dmspro_mys_cart`.`is_noticed` = 0
>   and `dmspro_mys_ci`.`created_at` < 2019-10-09 15:51:37 group by
>   `dmspro_mys_cart`.`cart_id`)

How I can fix this?

Thank you!

UPDATE: dmspro_mys_ is my prefix

Answer (score -1):

Your error message does not align with your query.

In the error message an alias named "dmspro_mys_ci" is mentioned, but it does not exist in your query.

Can you please double check this?

Basically your are debuggen the wrong query.

*Update*

As laravel is setup with prefixing database tables, the alias "ci" is also prefixed.
When referencing this alias in a DB::raw() the table/alias will not automatically be prefixed, so you have to do that yourself by changing:

`\DB::raw('MIN(ci.created_at) AS created_at')`

to:

`\DB::raw('MIN(dmspro_mys_ci.created_at) AS created_at')`

Comment: Then you need to change `\DB::raw('MIN(ci.created_at) AS created_at')` to `\DB::raw('MIN(dmspro_mys_ci.created_at) AS created_at')` to match your alias that is also prefixed.